# Por que o seguinte código imprime 'None' ao invés da lista?

Tags: python, algoritmo, lista

O programa deve receber valores, numa quantidade especificada pelo usuário. Preciso que uma lista seja criada com esses valores. Por que este código não funciona?

```
quantidade = int(raw_input())
inicio = 0
lista1 = list()
while inicio < quantidade:
    valor = int(raw_input())
    inicio = inicio + 1
    lista2 = lista1.append(valor)
print lista2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
quantidade = int(raw_input())
inicio = 0
lista1 = list()
while inicio < quantidade:
    valor = int(raw_input())
    inicio = inicio + 1
    lista1.append(valor)
print lista1
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 1):

Você está atribuindo o retorno do método append a uma variável e imprimindo, porém esse método não retorna nada. O append apenas adiciona um valor ao final da lista. O correto é fazer como o @M8n respondeu.